# Как сделать Toast круглым?

Tags: android, android-toast

Сделал кастомный Toast, цвет, текст, всё устраивает. Никак не могу найти инфо как сделать форму круглой. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#63AB3D"
    android:alpha="0.8">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FCFDFF"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: скиньте xml-код кастомного Toast. Возможно там можно только поменять shape

Comment: @TimurVI скинул

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте xml в папке Drawable (введете свои цвета)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#666666"/>

   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

И установите в ваш layout

```
android:background="@drawable/toast_shape"
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался). Пересидел за ноутом).